# How to set a const int to maximum in C++?

Tags: c++, integer, max, constants, numeric-limits

I have a static const member and would like to set it to the maximum integer. I'm trying the following:

```
const static int MY_VALUE = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
```

But get the following error:

> error: in-class initializer for static data member is not a constant
>   expression

Is there any solution to this? How can a function *not* return a constant expression?

**EDIT:** Adding -std=c++11 fixed the issue. My roommate tells me that the compiler (pre C++11) isn't smart enough to decide that std::numeric_limits::max() doesn't mutate anything else, and so is not considered constant. Is that possibly the reason for this error?

Comment: What compiler(or more importantly what C++ headers), what options? Works for me in clang with std=c++11.

Comment: I'm currently using clang-700.1.81

Comment: Most functions aren't usable in constant expressions. For example `printf`. It can't print output at compile time.

Comment: Compiles and links fine in VC 2015. `#include <limits> struct S { const static int MY_VALUE = std::numeric_limits<int>::max(); }; int main() {}` Compiled like this: `cl /nologo /EHsc /Za /W4 stackoverflow.cpp`

Comment: In Visual Studio 2015 works fine with `#include <limits.h>`. No errors and `MY_VALUE` is `2147483647`.

Comment: Compiling with `-std=c+11`?

Comment: You should compile with -std=c++11

Comment: @JuliaStefanyshyna: `<limits.h>` is wrong. It must be `<limits>`. In fact, this will lead to a compilation error in VC 2015.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I tried with `<limits.h>` and it worked. No errors. But you're right, it was my auto typing, of course I should use `<limits>`

Comment: @JuliaStefanyshyna: Well, define "it" :) That is, code + compiler options.

Comment: By the way, `MY_VALUE` is a bad name for something that's not a macro. The notion of using ALL_CAPS for constants makes sense in C (where you use macros for constants) and in Java (where there are no macros), but in C++ it will cause only troubles.

Comment: Please ask a new question for a new question.

Comment: @ChristianHackl MY_VALUE is just a placeholder for this question

Comment: @Xenon: Yes, but a suspiciously named one! :)

Comment: @ChristianHackl so that sounds like an answer to the whole question :) Compiler & options.

Comment: @JuliaStefanyshyna: Yeah. Unfortunately, people usually neglect to add this information to questions about compilation problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A constant must be initialized from a constant expression (an expression evaluable at compile-time).

In C++03, the set of constant operations you could build constant expressions from was extremely tight. Only bare integrals and mathematical operations on those.

In order to use a user-defined function in a constant expression, you need:

- C++11, or greater
- said function to be marked `constexpr`

This is why adding the `-std=c++11` flag to Clang helped: it allowed `constexpr` and "switched" to the improved Standard Library implementation which uses `constexpr` for `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()`.

*Note: if you use a more recent version of Clang, C++11 will be the default and no flag will be necessary to allow `constexpr`.*

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
#include <climits>
const static int MY_VALUE = INT_MAX;
```

Answer (score 0):

> If a static data member is of const integral or const enumeration
> type, its declaration in the class definition can specify a
> constant-initializer which shall be an integral constant expression
> (5.19). In that case, the member can appear in integral constant
> expressions.
>
> The member shall still be defined in a name- space scope if it is used in the program and the namespace scope definition shall not contain an initializer.

`numeric_limits` `max()` isn't an integral constant, that's compile time constant.

Comment: In C++11 the members of `numeric_limits` were made `constexpr`, so now are constants.

Comment: @BoPersson Which means they will be able to be used as a compile-time constant... I see